# stable-baselines3 loading a model error. what does ResourceWarning: unclosed file mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, stable-baselines

I am receiving an error when loading a model, which only appears in a custom environment.  The model trains fine and I can predict after training.  However, if I try to reload the model I receive the following error:

```
ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name='saved_models\\best_model.zip'>
```

Here is the full error dump

```
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydev_ipython\matplotlibtools.py", line 30, in do_enable_gui
    enable_gui(guiname)
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydev_ipython\inputhook.py", line 540, in enable_gui
    return gui_hook(app)
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydev_ipython\inputhook.py", line 176, in enable_qt
    from pydev_ipython.qt_for_kernel import QT_API, QT_API_PYQT5
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydev_ipython\qt_for_kernel.py", line 116, in <module>
    QtCore, QtGui, QtSvg, QT_API = load_qt(api_opts)
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydev_ipython\qt_loaders.py", line 276, in load_qt
    if not can_import(api):
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydev_ipython\qt_loaders.py", line 152, in can_import
    if not has_binding(api):
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydev_ipython\qt_loaders.py", line 115, in has_binding
    import imp
  File "C:\Users\craig.evans\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\imp.py", line 31, in <module>
    warnings.warn("the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib and slated "
DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib and slated for removal in Python 3.12; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
Exception ignored in: <_io.FileIO name='saved_models\\best_model.zip' mode='rb' closefd=True>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\craig.evans\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\base_class.py", line 659, in load
    data, params, pytorch_variables = load_from_zip_file(
ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name='saved_models\\best_model.zip'>
```

Curious if anyone has seen this before and knows how to resolve the issue.

Here is some example code which works.  If I change the environment to my custom gym environment the error occurs

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from random import seed

import gym
import numpy as np
import torch as th

from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.utils import set_random_seed
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import SubprocVecEnv
from stable_baselines3 import TD3
from stable_baselines3.common.monitor import Monitor
from stable_baselines3.common.results_plotter import load_results, ts2xy
from stable_baselines3.common.callbacks import BaseCallback


platform = 1 # 1: surface book, 2: work machine
num_env = 8
total_timesteps = 1_000_000 #10_000_000      # run this many total steps
save_in_steps = 50_000          # save the network after this many steps
number_training_steps = int(total_timesteps/save_in_steps)
NSTEPS = 2000           
VF_COEFF = 1.0
ENT_COEFF = 0.005
LEARNING_RATE = 0.0005 # changed from 0.0001
MINIBATCHES = 100  # changed from 128
EPOCHS = 5

results_folder = '.\\saved_models\\'
run_name = 'Sim_' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
tensorboard_log_location = '.\\tensorboard\\'


best_mean_reward, n_steps = -np.inf, 0


class SaveOnBestTrainingRewardCallback(BaseCallback):
    """
    Callback for saving a model (the check is done every ``check_freq`` steps)
    based on the training reward (in practice, we recommend using ``EvalCallback``).

    :param check_freq:
    :param log_dir: Path to the folder where the model will be saved.
      It must contains the file created by the ``Monitor`` wrapper.
    :param verbose: Verbosity level: 0 for no output, 1 for info messages, 2 for debug messages
    """
    def __init__(self, check_freq: int, log_dir: str, verbose: int = 1):
        super(SaveOnBestTrainingRewardCallback, self).__init__(verbose)
        self.check_freq = check_freq
        self.log_dir = log_dir
        self.save_path = os.path.join(log_dir, "best_model")
        self.best_mean_reward = -np.inf

    def _init_callback(self) -> None:
        # Create folder if needed
        if self.save_path is not None:
            os.makedirs(self.save_path, exist_ok=True)

    def _on_step(self) -> bool:
        if self.n_calls % self.check_freq == 0:

          # Retrieve training reward
          simResults = load_results(self.log_dir)
          try:
              x, y = ts2xy(simResults, "timesteps")
              if len(x) > 0:
                  # Mean training reward over the last 100 episodes
                  mean_reward = np.mean(y[-100:])
                  if self.verbose >= 1:
                    print(f"Num timesteps: {self.num_timesteps}")
                    print(f"Best mean reward: {self.best_mean_reward:.2f} - Last mean reward per episode: {mean_reward:.2f}")

                  # New best model, you could save the agent here
                  if mean_reward > self.best_mean_reward:
                      self.best_mean_reward = mean_reward
                      # Example for saving best model
                      if self.verbose >= 1:
                        print(f"Saving new best model to {self.save_path}")
                      self.model.save(self.save_path)
          except:
              print('Error loading results')
              print(simResults)

        return True


def make_env(env_id, rank: int, seed: int = 0, log_dir: str = ''):
    '''
    Utility function for multiprocessed env.
    
    env_id:    configuration information for the environment
    param rank:    index of the subprocess
    param seed:    the inital seed for RNG
    '''
    def _init():
        
        env = gym.make(env_id)

        env.seed(seed + rank)
        log_file = os.path.join(log_dir, str(rank)) if log_dir is not None else None
        return Monitor(env, log_file)
    set_random_seed(seed)
    return _init


def get_policyNetwork()-> dict:
    '''https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/sde/guide/custom_policy.html
    '''
    policyNetwork = dict(activation_fn = th.nn.ReLU, 
                         net_arch = dict(vf=[256, 256], pi=[256, 256]))

    return policyNetwork


if __name__ == '__main__':

    os.makedirs(results_folder, exist_ok=True)
    

    env = SubprocVecEnv([make_env(
                                 env_id     = 'LunarLanderContinuous-v2',
                                 rank       = i, 
                                 seed       = 0, 
                                 log_dir    = results_folder
                                 ) for i in range(num_env)])

    customPolicy = get_policyNetwork()

    #https://medium.com/aureliantactics/ppo-hyperparameters-and-ranges-6fc2d29bccbe
    model = PPO(
                 policy             = 'MlpPolicy',
                 env                = env,
                 verbose            = 1, 
                 vf_coef            = VF_COEFF,
                 n_epochs           = EPOCHS,
                 ent_coef           = ENT_COEFF,
                 learning_rate      = LEARNING_RATE,
                 tensorboard_log    = tensorboard_log_location,
                 n_steps            = NSTEPS,
                 batch_size         = MINIBATCHES,
                 policy_kwargs      = customPolicy,
                 device             = 'auto'
     )

    saveCallback = SaveOnBestTrainingRewardCallback(check_freq = save_in_steps, log_dir = results_folder)

    savedModel = results_folder + 'best_model.zip' 
    model.load(savedModel)

    model.learn(total_timesteps = total_timesteps, reset_num_timesteps = False, callback = saveCallback, progress_bar = True)

    inputResult = input('Would you like to render? (y/n): ')

    if inputResult =='y':
        env_render = gym.make('LunarLanderContinuous-v2')

        dones = False
        obs = env_render.reset()
        while dones == False:
            action, _states = model.predict(obs)
            obs, rewards, dones, info = env_render.step(action)
            env_render.render()
```

Comment: Would you mind posting code that generates this error?

Comment: Sorry, updated the post with some code

Comment: The warning symbolizes that your file was not properly closed. Without having any further information about your custom environment, I would assume that your parallel environments have some conflict during overwriting the same file `best_model.zip`.